# Not sure how to use QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt

i want to switch from different QWidgets with a button press but not sure how to do it, when i run this, i click the button and nothing happens, my code below:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <qstackedwidget.h>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_level_2Button_pressed()
{
    QWidget *page_1 = new QWidget;
    QWidget *page_2 = new QWidget;
    QStackedWidget *stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
    stackedWidget->addWidget(page_1);
    stackedWidget->addWidget(page_2);
    stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(page_2);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, I'm pretty new c++ and I'm struggling to understand how to use QStackedWidgets, thanks.

Comment: You never invoke [`show()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) on `stackedWidget`.  As an aside, you should `#include <QStackedWidget>` rather than `qstackedwidget.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you have not added the widget to the main window: I would add `setCentralWidget(stackedWidget)` in your code. You can also do this through a layout: just create a layout (e.g:`QVBoxLayout`), add your widget to the layout (`layout_name->addWidget(stackedWidget)` and use `setLayout(layout_name)`. Just don't forget to include `QLayout` if you want to use layouts.

If you want further information on `QStackedWidget`, you can use the well-explained [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).